# XSD datatype for multi-line strings?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've noticed that multi-line strings aren't valid `xsd:string`s. According to the [XML 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Char), `xsd:string` can contain only characters matching `[\u1-\uD7FF]|[\uE000-\uFFFD]|[\u10000-\u10FFFF]`, which newline doesn't match. In JavaScript:

```
/[\u1-\uD7FF]|[\uE000-\uFFFD]|[\u10000-\u10FFFF]/.test("\n");
// returns false
```

Given this, what is a valid XSD datatype for multi-line strings?

Answer (score 1):

A newline is \u000A, which is within the allowed range.

Although your regex doesn't have any issues that jump out at me, your test is the problem.

Edit: According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for regex, Unicode escapes take 4 hex digits. I suspect your problem is that you're including the higher planes in your test. I haven't checked the ECMA spec, but I could believe that this is causing problems with your regex.

Comment: `test` is native method for regular expressions in JavaScript. Would you consider it buggy?
However, the same thing happens in Python:
`bool(re.match("[\u1-\uD7FF]|[\uE000-\uFFFD]|[\u10000-\u10FFFF]", "\n"))`
`# false`

Comment: I guess the problem must be in the regular expression.

Comment: @jindrichm - `/[\u0001-\uD7ff\uE000-\uFFFD]/.test("\n")` works in JavaScript, so it does appear that higher planes cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

What the XML 1.1 specification actually says is

```
Char       ::=      [#x1-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

and I fail to see how anyone can read that as excluding #xA.

Comment: I agree. It happened because of the syntax for Unicode strings in regular expressions in JavaScript that requires 4 hexadecimal digits to be used (instead of `#x1` it needs `#x0001`).